# Combining Strings in ASP.NET Attributes

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I am trying to concat a string inside the attribute. I get an error. I think that it is related to my `Eval`. Is there a proper way to concat strings, or is this just not possible. The problem I believe is where I set the NavigateUrl.

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="lb" 
               runat="server" 
               Text='<%#Eval("Key.Id") %>' 
               NavigateUrl='ViewItem.aspx?id=' + '<%# Eval("Key.Id") %>'/>
```

Comment: Why don't you just do it in the code-behind?

Comment: @sub13 Its in a GridView. can I still do that?

Comment: Yep - I do it (see my answer)

Answer (score 3):

Short answer: `NavigateUrl='<%# Eval("Key.Id", "ViewItem.aspx?id={0}") %>'`

Longer explanation:

The problem in your code is that you are use data binding expression only for part of your web control attribute. You need to move everything inside the data binding expression.

First of all, a data binding expression is this:

```
<%# EXPRESSION %>
```

Basically the rule for using a data binding expression for a web control attribute is that the expression must be the only thing in the attribute:

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="lb" runat="server" 
  Text='<%# EXPRESSION %>'
  NavigateUrl='<%# EXPRESSION %>' />
```

So your first attribute, `Text`, is correct. But your second attribute, `NavigateUrl` is not correct. Because you put `ViewItem.aspx?id=` as the value for the attribute, leaving `+ '<%# Eval("Key.Id") %>'` outside any attribute but inside the control tag.

Here is the correct syntax:

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="lb" runat="server" 
  Text='<%# Eval("Key.Id") %>' 
  NavigateUrl='<%# Eval("Key.Id", "ViewItem.aspx?id={0}") %>'/>
```

Notice that we are using a format string as the second parameter for `Eval()`. This is equivalent to the following, more explicit, syntax:

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="lb" runat="server" 
  Text='<%# Eval("Key.Id") %>' 
  NavigateUrl='<%# String.Format("ViewItem.aspx?id={0}", Eval("Key.Id")) %>'/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I do when I have something in a gridview like this:

```
<img src='<%# GetDisImageLink(Eval("Disabilities").ToString()) %>' 
   alt="Disabilities" />
```

[CS code-behind]

```
public string GetDisImageLink(string dis)
{
    return "../../Content/Images/CardContactInfo/" + 
       (dis.Trim() == "Y" ? "DIS.png" : "Blank.png");
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Try this instead:

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="lb" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Key.Id") %>' NavigateUrl='ViewItem.aspx?id=<%# Eval("Key.Id") %>'/>
```

You don't need to concatenate