# Concatenate text in HTML attributes

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net

I want to concatenate text in html attributes. Is there a way to concatenate text inside the html code without coding in JavaScript? I am using asp .net. My code:

```html
<asp:ListItem Value="1" Text="<%$ Resources: LocalizedText, LastSession%>">
</asp:ListItem>
```

I just want to put characters `"<"` and `">"` at the beginning of the Text attribute and at the end. Something like this:

```html
<asp:ListItem Value="1" Text="<" + "<%$ Resources: LocalizedText, LastSession%>"> + ">"
</asp:ListItem>
```

Thanks to all!!

Comment: Possible soln.... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9025478/combining-strings-in-asp-net-attributes

Comment: It doesn't work for me. I just want to know if it is possible. If not, I will do on code.